# PFC Boost Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, boost, power-factor-correction

I have two questions regarding PFC boost Converter.

1. Why boost converter is preferred over buck for PFC?
2. What is the difference between PFC boost converter and a traditional Boost converter?

Answer (score 3):

> *Why boost converter is preferred over buck for PFC?*

A boost circuit generates an output DC voltage that is higher than any part of the AC input voltage. This means that for any part of the AC waveform, the booster can (through clever manipulation by the controller) draw a sinewave current from the incoming AC supply.

This makes it look like a resistive load (the object of PFC).

That's the intention but, it doesn't quite work when the input AC voltage is passing through or close to 0 volts. Nevertheless, it's a good method with minor inconsistencies.

If instead you used a buck PFC circuit, you have to ensure that the buck's output voltage is close to 0 volts so that over the full AC input voltage cycle, it's nearly always "bucking" down to that low DC output voltage.

But, in many situations, you don't really want a low DC output voltage because the PFC circuit is usually driving some form of isolating power supply (such as a flyback circuit). Therefore, it is preferable to use a high DC voltage (as produced by a boost PFC circuit) in most applications.

> *What is the difference between PFC boost converter and a traditional
> Boost converter?*

It's all about the controller. The actual boost circuitry is a traditional booster but, it's made to draw a sinewave current from the incoming AC voltage by the controller. The big difference is the controller.

Answer (score 3):

> Why boost converter is preferred over buck for PFC?

There are, of course, couple of reasons but I'll mention only one here:

See the waveforms below for a buck PFC:

[image]

You can see that the conduction happens only when the instantaneous value of the rectified mains input is greater than or equal to the output voltage. And this

- brings a requirement of very bulky output capacitor for a stable output voltage. If you consider the hold-up requirement as well (generally 16 ms) the output caps will get even bulkier <sup>The ripple will quite possibly be higher than that in a boost PFC, even with a bulky capacitor</sup>. This basically means volumetric inefficiency.
- prevents us to design wide input range products because as the input voltage decreases the conduction range gets narrower, causing the I-THD (THD of input current) to skyrocket (e.g. for boost PFCs an I-THD of 10% can be considered high but for buck PFCs 10% is just a dream). Therefore, as Andy stated in his answer, the output voltage should be really low to keep the conduction range wide enough to supply the load effectively. But this is impractical because of the presence of high current demands for the next stage *(Imagine how difficult it would be for the DC-DC section of a 600W high-PF converter when the PFC bus voltage is 25V)*.

For a boost PFC, however, conduction happens during almost the entire period, making the I-THD and the ripple lower, therefore bringing more efficient and effective conversion. It's also good for the next stage which is generally an isolated converter because higher voltage brings lower currents for the same output power, in an expense of using high voltage switches of course. This is not a problem today, though, as the market offers millions of different options.

There are a few more advantages of the boost over buck such as the ease of gate drive (ground-referenced low-side switch instead of a high-side switch), and ease of surge management thanks to the presence of a direct connection from line input to output bulk caps.

---

> What is the difference between PFC boost converter and a traditional Boost converter?

I don't have anything to add as the other answers have good explanations.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to boost the voltage in order to have current flowing all the time. When the voltage in the AC cycle is low, the boost circuit tries to ensure that the output voltage is enough for current to flow.
2. Difference? There is no difference in the boost circuit itself. The control is where it is different. A ‘normal’ boost converter would output a constant voltage whereas a PFC has to track the changing AC mains voltage and maintain current. In a nutshell, the control circuit for a PFC is more complex.